# Glassfish Multiple Application Deployment

Tags: java, spring, glassfish

I currently have 4 Spring applications running in Glassfish 3.1. As it stands now, all 4 applications have almost the same jar files except for a few differences, around 2 or 3 jar files. What I would like to know are the following:
1. How to share the common jar files within the 4 applications?
2. Where to place the shared jar files in Glassfish?
3. When deploying a War file, will the war file need to contain inside it the shared jar file or not??

I've googled the answers for 1 and 2 but placing them to domain/lib as well as sub directories in /lib, didn't solve the problem.

The goal here is to minimize the possibility of having a permgen exception during application deployment because of deploying large files.

Am I doing anything wrong?

Pleadse advice.

Cheers!